# How do I load a Python module with custom globals using importlib?

Tags: python, python-module, python-importlib

I'm trying to put together a small build system in Python that generates Ninja files for my C++ project. Its behavior should be similar to CMake; that is, a `bldfile.py` script defines rules and targets and optionally recurses into one or more directories by calling `bld.subdir()`. Each `bldfile.py` script has a corresponding `bld.File` object. When the `bldfile.py` script is executing, the `bld` global should be predefined as that file's `bld.File` instance, *but only in that module's scope*.

Additionally, I would like to take advantage of Python's bytecode caching somehow, but the `.pyc` file should be stored in the build output directory instead of in a `__pycache__` directory alongside the `bldfile.py` script.

I know I should use `importlib` (requiring Python 3.4+ is fine), but I'm not sure how to:

1. Load and execute a module file with custom globals.
2. Re-use the bytecode caching infrastructure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but Python's "globals" are actually module-scoped already - each script's ``bld`` global will automatically be distinct (unless they explicitly import it from another module, or store it into another module).

Comment: I figured, but I'm not much of a Python programmer, so I just wanted to make that requirement clear in case it had any effect on the answer.

Comment: If you say custom globals, do you want to set them before importing the module?

Comment: @kazemakase Yes, I want them to be available when the module's code executes.

Comment: @DavidBrown I don't think this is possible, but it will be interesting to see how someone may prove me wrong. There are certainly easier ways to achieve your desired functionality without hacking imports. For example, you could define entry functions in the modules that perform all the work after the import is finished. Regarding `__pycache__`, I think it is [hard-coded](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Python/import.c#L22) although the definition seems to be unused. Can't elaborate an answer on the import stuff now; will check back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting globals into a module before execution is an interesting idea. However, I think it conflicts with several points of the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). In particular, it requires writing code in the module that depends on global values which are not explicitly defined, imported, or otherwise obtained - unless you know the particular procedure required to call the module.

This may be an obvious or slick solution for the specific use case but it is not very intuitive. In general, (Python) code should be explicit. Therefore, I would go for a solution where parameters are explicitly passed to the executing code. Sounds like functions? Right:

**bldfile.py**

```
def exec(bld):
    print('Working with bld:', bld)
    # ...
```

**calling the module:**

```
# set bld

# Option 1: static import
import bldfile
bldfile.exec(bld)

# Option 2: dynamic import if bldfile.py is located dynamically
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("unique_name", "subdir/subsubdir/bldfile.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
module.exec(bld)
```

That way no code (apart from the function definition) is executed when importing the module. The `exec` function needs to be called explicitly and when looking at the code inside `exec` it is clear where `bld` comes from.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer, even though it's not the solution I went with, because it's probably what most projects *should* do (and in fact, this is what WAF does). In my case, I wanted `bldfile.py` to appear more like a configuration file than a script file in the simplest cases. Compiling a library, for example, should be as simple as a single line: `bld.lib('foo', 'foo.cc')`. If I ever decide to make this tool usable outside of my C++ project, I would probably refactor it to use your approach.

Answer (score 1):

I studied `importlib`'s source code and since I don't intend to make a reusable `Loader`, it seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity. So I just settled on creating a module with `types.ModuleType`, adding `bld` to the module's `__dict__`, compiling and caching the bytecode with `compile`, and executing the module with `exec`. At a low level, that's basically all `importutil` does anyway.

Comment: Interesting solution. I don't know what you did exactly, but you probably don't need to use `ModuleType`. You can add `bld` directly to the globals  when calling `exec` on the code object. `exec(code, {'bld': bld})`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to overcome the lack of possibility by using dummy module, which would load its globals .

```
#service.py 
module = importlib.import_module('userset')
module.user = user 
module = importlib.import_module('config')

#config.py
from userset import *
#now you can use user from service.py
```